# AngularJS reevaluate directives on change of $location

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to write a nav menu that hides/displays information based on the path in the url being specified.

So far, I have the following:

```
.directive( "jkSection", function( $routeParams, $location ){

        var linker = function( scope, element, attrs){
            // Extract the first part of the path.  Used to match against the menu lists
            var currentPath = /^\/?([^/]+)/.exec($location.path())[1];

            // check to see if the path is the same as the attribute
            if( attrs.jkSection.toUpperCase() == currentPath.toUpperCase() )
                element.show();
            else
                element.hide();
        };

        return{
            restrict: "A",
            link: linker
        };
    });
```

Although this works on page load, when I change the location, the directive is not reapplied.  I figured I need to add a watch on the $location, but not sure what kind of callback I need to make such that my directives are reevaluated.

I think part of the issue is that the html that is using my `jk-section` directive (used in the sidebar.html view) is not part of the `ng-view` component.  But at the moment, I do not wish to refactor my layout.

```
    <div class="flex-row flex-row--gutter-less flex-hbox main-container">
        <div ng-include="'build/views/sidebar.html'" class="sidebar-wrapper"></div>
        <div class="main-content" ng-view></div>
    </div>
```

Secondly, is there a better way than parsing the $location.path() to pull information from the route?  Is there a way I can specify route names/aliases/etc directly in the `$route` object?

Comment: You could bind to location change events (i.e. `$locationChangeStart` or `$locationChangeSuccess`) in your directive scope using `$on`, which you can also pass a callback to be invoked.

Comment: @miqid - I realized that I can bind to the event `$locationChangeSuccess`, but I wasn't sure what to put in the callback function.  How do I tell the callback function to reevaluate the template?  Can you provide an example please?

Comment: I'm hazy on context here. Clarifying _why_ you need the template reevaluation might help with a more elegant solution. Regardless, if you want a template to be reevaluated, that's usually achieved by using the `$compile` service and re-adding the template element to the DOM (cf. source for [`ng-include`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngInclude.js#L218) demonstrates one way).

Comment: @miqid Basically, I have a bunch of links in the my template.  I want some links to be hidden and others to be shown depending on the route selected.  I figured I could use a directive that specifies my condition for showing the link and have my directive.link function evaluate whether or not to show the element.  But that means that I need to have the directive re-read the template/ reapply the link function upon a $location change.

Comment: @EricB. There's no reason to "re-read the template/reapply the link function" - just keep track of a scope variable, and use `ng-hide`/`ng-show`/`ng-if` in the template, based on that scope variable. Change the scope variable in the location change event based on whatever condition

Comment: @Ian The problem is that I have several elements each with different conditions.  I figured a directive would be more appropriate that a controller with a scope variable, but if there is a better way to do it via a controller, I would love to hear it.  I can forsee using a scope hash array (one element for each condition), but find that a little ugly/hacky.

Comment: @EricB. I never mentioned controllers...directives have their own scope, and that's what I was referring to. Here's an example (very simple) of what I meant: http://jsfiddle.net/NY24J/

Comment: @Ian - Thanks.  I hadn't thought of that; when I think of scope variables, I automatically think of controllers.  I'll rethink my approach to use directive scope vars; it might work quite nicely actually and be more in line with Angular's philosophy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to utilise `ng-hide/show/if` in your template, put the expected link behaviour inside another function and run it as the callback of the event you are listening for.

```
var linker = function( scope, element, attrs){
    function render () {
      // Extract the first part of the path.  Used to match against the menu lists
      var currentPath = /^\/?([^/]+)/.exec($location.path())[1];

      // check to see if the path is the same as the attribute
      if( attrs.jkSection.toUpperCase() == currentPath.toUpperCase() )
          element.show();
      else
          element.hide();
    }

    scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', render);

    // Not sure if $locationChangeSuccess triggers on initial load. 
    // If yes, remove this line. 
    render();
};
```

With that being said, `ng-hide/show/if` in your template is probably the better way to go, simply set a $scope variable instead of doing `element.show()/hide()`.

Comment: Awesome.  Works perfectly.  I am new to AngularJS and would have preferred using ng-hide/show/if, however, there are several different elements being hidden, each with their own conditions that have to be satisfied.  I am setting the condition in a parameter and figured that using a directive was more appropriate than setting a $scope variable in the controller.  If I am mistaken, I would love to learn how to do it better.